# C# topshelf didn't want add items to database

Tags: c#, database, topshelf

Hello i have a problem with topshelf.I want to create a windows service which can add something to database and repeated on every minute. When i run topshelf application as a console application that's all works fine but when service was installed this items are not added to database. In windows services i can see that service was running.
Anyone can help me?

```
  HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
        {
            hostConfigurator.Service<MojaUsluga>(serviceConfigurator =>
            {
                serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(() => new MojaUsluga());
                serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted(MojaUsluga => MojaUsluga.Start());
                serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped(MojaUsluga => MojaUsluga.Stop());
            });

            hostConfigurator.RunAsLocalSystem();
            hostConfigurator.StartAutomatically();

            hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName("RSSv");
            hostConfigurator.SetDescription("RssReader using Topshelf");
            hostConfigurator.SetServiceName("RSS");
        });


  public void Start()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timerTEST = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        timerTEST.AutoReset = true;
        timerTEST.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(doIt);
        timerTEST.Start();    

    }
```

Comment: Does the service account have permissions to write to the database?

Comment: i think yes but where i can check this?

Comment: I suggest using a profiler to a) see if the service is connecting to the database and b) to look for authentication failures